# How to Find the Link text of any Element Automatically without any Human Interference in Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, instagram

---

> **Before you Read Question Do See the Image Link. There is a Link Below which will Describe The Question From Image** ***So Good Luck***

[Instagram Hashtag Image for Explaining my Project and Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or0yU.jpg)

I am Trying to Make a Software or A Bot Basically.

1. Who will Fetch This URL -

`https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/pubggaming/`

2. Find an Element of Follow. *(You can see The Picture)*
3. If there is an Option of Follow then It will Follow Elif There is Following in the Page then It will Pass Forward to next Image. ***(will repeat same Stuff)***

   **What I needed to be Done is.**
   I want to Create a Follow - Unfollow Software on My own, who will get the name of the person
   (**You can see it Blue-marked in Image above**) with the Help of Selenium (Python)
   who will `(find_element_by_link_text)` Automatically without the help of Human.

and store that  `(find_element_by_link_text)` output on a **MyFile.txt *File*** 
so that I can remember the name of Those Who I Followed by This Bot and in Future, I can Make my Bot Unfollow them Automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend finding your Element by XPATH and from there you can do anything. Automation in Webbrowsers usually contain 2 Steps.

1. Finding your Element (I'd recommend using XPATH, because you can build logic and find any element)
2. Interacting with your element. (clicking it, fetching data from it or giving input)

It's literally the same for your project, for example to find the follow button I'd use:

```
followButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Follow')]")
```

Than you could interact with it like that:

```
followButton.click()
```